Freeradius error when restarting
I get this error when I run sudo freeradius -X on my daloradius server
/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/mschap[260]: Too many closing braces
Errors reading or parsing /etc/freeradius/3.0/radiusd.conf


Without knowing anything about freeradius, it's evident from the error message that your config has an error with too many closing braces (most likely ), or another parenthesis type. Please go through your config for errors.
